# What are the leading methods for temporally interpolating wind data?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, extreme-weather

Weather providers, such as GFS and ECMWF usually provide their data in 3-6 hour intervals.

What would be the best method to interpolate between the intervals to get a good intermediate wind model?

I found [this paper](https://esrl.noaa.gov/gsd/eds/gfesuite/pubs/Interpolating-Between-Grids-of-Meteorological-Data-for-AFPS.pdf) - it suggests interpolating speed and wind direction separately, but this still seems a bit simplistic to me...

Comment: Some models provide output more frequently, but with a shorter forecast length (24 hours versus hundreds), e.g., HRRR, as seen at https://www.tropicaltidbits.com/analysis/models/?model=hrrr&region=us&pkg=ref_frzn&runtime=2020113021&fh=3

Comment: If you're willing to pay there is this service at [link]https://www.predictwind.com/why-predictwind-forecast/[/link] that looks to focus on wind. You could also see what their free services are like but my assumption would be that they will paywall the hourly stuff.

As stated above, the HRRR is a good model for short-term but high granularity, only problem is that it's only in America. There's also the NBM which NCEP is starting to transition to as their main model.

For what purpose are you looking for this type of wind forecasting? Because there are industry specific models to use.